# How to Reflect input of a textbox into another textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code to reflect the text of a textbox1 into another textbox that called textbox1a on keyup event. 
i separate them with the same background. to show each result into specific input. but when i write in first text box it is repeat text to others. 
how can i separate them?
here is my code :

```js
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
   var className = $(this).attr('class').replace('valueEnter','').trim();
   $("."+className).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
TextBox 1a : <input type="text" class="textBox1 valueEnter" style="background:#ccc;"/><br/>
TextBox 1b : <input type="text" class="textBox1 valueEnter" style="background:pink;"/> <br/> 
TextBox 2 : <input type="text" class="textBox2 valueEnter"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="second">
Show text 1a : <input type="text" class="textBox1" style="background:#ccc;"/> <br/> 
Show text 1b : <input type="text" class="textBox1" style="background:pink;"/> <br/>
show text2 : <input type="text" class="textBox2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: While the currently accepted answer shows what you want, for better answers in future it would be better to more clearly communicate that in the question you're asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.index()` here to find index of input inside `.first` and then use `.eq()` to change value input at that index inside `.second`

```js
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
   var index = $('.first .textBox1').index(this);
   var className = $(this).attr('class').replace('valueEnter','').trim();
   $(".second ."+className).eq(index).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
TextBox 1a : <input type="text" class="textBox1 valueEnter" style="background:#ccc;"/><br/>
TextBox 1b : <input type="text" class="textBox1 valueEnter" style="background:pink;"/> <br/> 
TextBox 2 : <input type="text" class="textBox2 valueEnter"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="second">
Show text 1a : <input type="text" class="textBox1" style="background:#ccc;"/> <br/> 
Show text 1b : <input type="text" class="textBox1" style="background:pink;"/> <br/>
show text2 : <input type="text" class="textBox2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a problem that these inputs are repeate dinamically and i can not change the classnames

Comment: how are they generated? can you add some data attribute to these tags or id?

Comment: no i can't add anything to them. is there a way to show the result of first input of first div to the first input of next div? and second input of fist div to second input of next div? can i write my code with this conditions?

Comment: when i write in TextBox 1a, the value goes to Show text 1b

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I'm not sure if I understand the question completely, but you are searching for something like this?

```js
var enter_idx = 0;
var reflect_idx = 0;
// This code supposes a relation between textboxes:
// the first ".textBox1 .valueEnter" input must be reflected 
// in the first ".textBox1" that does not have ".valueEnter" class
// if the logic is different, you have to modify it.
$(function() {  
  $('.textBox1').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('value-enter')) {
      $(this).attr('data-target', "#TextBox" + enter_idx);
      enter_idx += 1;
    } else {
      $(this).attr('id', "TextBox" + reflect_idx);
      reflect_idx += 1;
    }
  });
  // Now let's install the callbacks
  $('.value-enter').each( function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
      var target = String($(this).attr('data-target'));
      $(target).val($(this).val());
    }); 
  });
});
```

```css
/* 
I'm using different colors because I have colorblindness,
and I cannot see difference between pink and grey

Notice that those classes are not used in the JS code are only
for displaying purposes
*/
.textbox1a_v {
  background: green;
}

.textbox1b_v {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
TextBox 1a : 
<input type="text" class="textbox1a_v textBox1 value-enter"/><br/>
TextBox 1b : 
<input type="text" class="textbox1b_v textBox1 value-enter"/> <br/> 
Show text 1a : 
<input type="text" class="textbox1a_v textBox1"/> <br/> 
Show text 1b : 
<input type="text" class="textbox1b_v textBox1"/> <br/>
</div>
```

I actually don't get why there is also `textBox2`...

Comment: yes i want this. but there is a problem with id . because this fields generate dinamically i cant set id for them

Comment: @inaz you can use class names also as target. just use `dot` instead of `hash`

Comment: @inaz maybe now I understand your question, let me work a little on it...

Comment: If theyre generated dynamically just use a counter or the key as the ID.  would that not work?